# What is the meaning of the last phrase here? 但上涨的部分又被不断上涨的成本抵消

Tags: meaning

Can anyone help with the last part of this text. I put the section title and the whole paragraph, so you might be able to decipher it. I can't see what they are saying. 2 other times people here have said 'that is weird text', but it comes direct from my Business Chinese book, it was not written by me! Is it bad Chinese?

促进中国制鞋业成长。

欧盟鞋类反倾销对中国鞋的直接影响

压力主要体现在皮鞋出口数量与金额上。曾有数据统计显示，维持反倾销税的一段时间内，中国对欧盟的鞋类出口增幅明显下降，单价却显著上升，但上涨的部分又被不断上涨的成本抵消。

单价却显著上升，
the unit price however clearly increases, (because of the anti-dumping tax, I suppose)

(I can't figure this part out. How does it relate to the above?)

但上涨的部分又被不断上涨的成本抵消。

but  increase price part again by the non-stop increase of (production) costs equal to/counteracted,

Comment: The original text was not written in the most clear way possible. There is a omission which caused your confusion. What it was trying to say is '(the price increase did not turn into higher profit because) the increase was cancelled out by the ever increasing costs.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through this part piece by piece.

压力主要体现在皮鞋出口数量与金额上 = The pressure is mainly seen in the number and price of exports.

曾有数据统计显示 = Statistics have shown clearly that

维持反倾销税的一段时间内，中国对欧盟的鞋类出口增幅明显下降 = after maintaining the anti-dumping law for some time, the growth rate of China's shoe exports has a noticeable decline.

单价却显著上升 = However, the price of the shoes kept increasing.

So up till now, we have one part that is increasing (the shoe price) and one part that is decreasing (the growth rate of the shoe exports).

Now let's look at final part:

There are 2 nouns phrases that we need to figure out.
上涨的部分 = The part that is growing. As we noted above, this is the price of the shoe.

不断上涨的成本 = The ever increasing costs of making/exporting the shoe.

Then it becomes:

但 [上涨的部分] 又被 [不断上涨的成本] 抵消

抵消 means "canceled out" and "又被" means "have been" and 但 means "but."

Then putting all this together it means:
Yet, the growing price is being canceled out by the rising costs of making/exporting the shoes.

Comment: So, 单价却显著上升 does not refer to the price increase due to the 反倾销税, rather a general increase in the unit price over time? That was not clear to me. You get that from 单价却显著上升 'unit price however remarkable rise= 'the unit price has seen a remarkable rise'?? 谢谢您！

Comment: Well, the thing indicates that even though the growth rate of exports decreased, the sale price of the shoe increased (perhaps due to 反倾销税 changes or to increased demand? it's not clear).